# How to add 1 number to variable each time it loops on iMacros?

Tags: loops, firefox, imacros

I'm using firefox iMacros addons for an automation. I got stuck at one point. When I execute the following code, it works! But, I want to increase one variable named **CONTENT** each time. Like, in this script its executed for account no- **001**.

Now, I want to loop with this script with increase of the **CONTENT** no. I mean, after first time execution it will execute for **CONTENT** no- **002**, then for **003** and so on. What change should I do with this script to make it works?

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:logInBankForm ATTR=NAME:userID CONTENT=myID
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:logInBankForm ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=myPassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:logInBankForm ATTR=SRC:http://example.com/pages/login.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:logInBankForm ATTR=ID:join103
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:logInBankForm ATTR=TXT:Transaction<SP>Profile
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:accountNo CONTENT=001
DS CMD=KEY X=0 Y=0 CONTENT={ENTER}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[0].totalTransactionPerDay CONTENT=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[0].totalAmountPerDay CONTENT=300000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[0].totalTransactionPerMonth CONTENT=20
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[0].totalAmountPerMonth CONTENT=1000000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[0].maxAmountPerTransaction CONTENT=200000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[1].totalTransactionPerDay CONTENT=4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[1].totalAmountPerDay CONTENT=300000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[1].totalTransactionPerMonth CONTENT=15
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[1].totalAmountPerMonth CONTENT=1000000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:indexProfileList[1].maxAmountPerTransaction CONTENT=200000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=FONT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=TXT:Execute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a more universal solution is needed, you may try to change these two lines

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:accountNo CONTENT=001
DS CMD=KEY X=0 Y=0 CONTENT={ENTER}
```

for

```
SET !LOOP 1
SET accNo EVAL("('00' + {{!LOOP}}).slice(-3);")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:accountNo CONTENT={{accNo}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
DS CMD=KEY X=0 Y=0 CONTENT={ENTER}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=13
WAIT SECONDS=6
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
```

---

**Old info.** 

 Replace the line

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:accountNo CONTENT=001
```

with

```
SET !LOOP 1
SET accNo EVAL("('00' + {{!LOOP}}).slice(-3);")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:customerTransactionProfileForm ATTR=NAME:accountNo CONTENT={{accNo}}
```

and play the whole macro in loop mode.

---

BTW, you provided a code that works only in 'iMacros Browser', but not in 'iMacros' for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm! But, if the Acc no. 002 is not found than the loops stops!! It doesn't check either for the acc no. 003 or any further. Which code I have to change to make this idea implemented like, if any acc. no serial can't execute it will go for the next acc. no with iteration/loops continues?

You said that the code only works with 'iMacros Browser' not with 'iMacros' for firefox! Which measure should I take to make it works for both 'iMacros Browser' and 'iMacros' for firefox? Thanks in advance.